# ItextSharp return a corrupted file after editing existing pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, itext

I am new to itextSharp. What I am doing is just editing the old file and instead of saving the new file on the server I just want it to download at the time. but unfortunately after editing the file and being downloaded, file display a message **cannot open the file. It may be corrupted**.

Here is my code.

```
public FileStreamResult export( int ? id)
    {
        string pathin = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/PDF/input.pdf"));


        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathin);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(size);

        // open the writer
        //FileStream ms = new FileStream(pathout, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        document.Open();

        // the pdf content
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        // select the font properties
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 18f);

        // write the text in the pdf content
        cb.BeginText();
        string text = "this is text";
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 500, 500, 0);
        cb.EndText();
        cb.BeginText();
        text = "this is my post";
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 600, 400, 0);
        cb.EndText();

        // create the new page and add it to the pdf
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);


        ms.Position = 0;
        document.Close();
        //ms.Close();

        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();


        return File(ms, "application/pdf","test.pdf");
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the position of the memory stream before closing the document:

```
    ms.Position = 0;
    document.Close();
```

As the trailer of the pdf in the result stream is written during the closing of the document, your change of stream position causes the pdf trailer to be written over the pdf header and the stream position thereafter to not be at the start.

Instead first close the document and the reader (the writer implicitly is closed by closing the document) and reset the stream position thereafter:

```
    document.Close();
    reader.Close();

    ms.Position = 0;
    return File(ms, "application/pdf","test.pdf");
```

Comment: yeah. thank you. Now i am thinking how can i miss this point. Great man!